# If $a,b \in \mathbb N$, prove that $a^2+(a+1)^2\ne b^4+(b+1)^4$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've only shown it's true when $b^2 \ge a$. I found that out after a bit of factoring. I got that $$(b^2+a)(b^2-a)=-(b^2+a+2b+2)(b^2-a+2b)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a^2+(a+1)^2=b^4+(b+1)^4$ and let $q=\frac {b^2}a\in \mathbb Q$. By substituting $a$ with $qb^2$ and rearranging we obtain the quadratic equation (i.e. quadratic in $q$ with coeffivcents depending on $b$)
$$ b^3\cdot q^2+ b\cdot q - (b^3+2b^2+3b+2)=0.$$
As $q$ is rational, the discriminant
$$ D = b^2+4b^3(b^3+2b^2+3b+2)=b^2\cdot(4b^4+8b^3+12b^2+8b+1)$$
must be a square and so must $4b^4+8b^3+12b^2+8b+1=\frac D{b^2}$.
But 
$$ 4b^4+8b^3+12b^2+8b+1=(2b^2+2b+1)^2+4b^2+4b>(2b^2+2b+1)^2$$
(because $b>0$) and 
$$ 4b^4+8b^3+12b^2+8b+1=(2b^2+2b+2)^2-3<(2b^2+2b+2)^2$$
i.e. $4b^4+8b^3+12b^2+8b+1$ is between two consecutive squares.

Comment: Why do you substitute $a$ with $qb^2$? Seems to be that it should be $\frac{b^2}{1}$? I'm not sure how this affects the rest (if it does).

Comment: If we actually substitute $a$ with $b^2\over q$, we get to the same conclusion: $$2b^4({1\over q^2}) + 2b^2({1\over q}) - (2b^4 + 4b^3 + 6b^2 + 4b) = 0\\ D=4 b^4 (4 b^4+8 b^3+12 b^2+8 b+1)$$ And thus surprisingly we get the same thing $\Rightarrow$ $\:4 b^4+8 b^3+12 b^2+8 b+1$ has to be a perfect square.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Proof by contradiction. Assume equality, show that:

$$ a^2 + a + 1 = (b^2 + b + 1)^2 $$

**Hint:** $a^2 + a + 1 $ is a perfect square if and only if $a = 0 $. Bound it between two squares.

Hence $a=0, b = 0 $ is the only solution (and I'm guessing you don't include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$).